# Unity3D Making timescale freeze and resume

Tags: unity, c#

So, I'm  trying to make it where when a popup(Ui panel and text) appears, the game's time(timescale) would freeze. Then when the user enters input and clicks enter button, the popup would disappear and time would resume.

How could I make time follow this?

Answer (score 2):

To Freeze Time (Game Time)

```
Time.timeScale = 0;
```

To restore Time (Game Time)

```
Time.timeScale = 1;
```

Comment: Does this also pause UI? If not, how do you pause in-game UI that shouldn't be interactive when the game's paused?

Comment: It won't unpause time when I have the game unpause. I tried setting it back to Time.timeScale  = 1 when the user clicks on the enter button, but it won't allow time to resume

Comment: Be aware that logic inside of `FixedUpdate` will not be called, as this function is directly influenced by Time.timeScale. I had a problem using timescale to pause due to this specific interaciton.